# Software like LiVES Video Editing for Windows 7

Tags: audio-recording, software, windows

Newbie here. I am wondering if there is any alternative for the open source LiVES Video Editing software (http://lives.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7?
Or, can the lives source be compiled on Windows with Cygwin? Are there 64-bit alternatives?
Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://lives.sourceforge.net/index.php?do=downloads) it says that you can run LiVES from a DVD or bootable USB. Would that work for you?

Comment: I saw that, and that would probably work stop-gap, but was looking for a long-term solution. Thanks for the pointer.